Why is my room database data non persistent?
I have an android app that uses room database and dagger. I tried all the answers I found on the internet, and this is my last resort as I'm on the week 2 of solving this problem.
My Setup:
com.example.app
|-configurations
  |-AppComponent.kt
  |-AppDB.kt
  |-AppModule.kt
  |-MyApp.kt



@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(baseViewModel: BaseViewModel)
}


@Database(entities = [
    User::class
], version = 1, exportSchema = true)

abstract class AppDB : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userRepository(): IUserRepository

    companion object{

        @Volatile
        private var db_instance: AppDB? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getAppDBInstance(context : Context): AppDB {

            return db_instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDB::class.java,
                    "TransitPayDB.db3"
                ).allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
                db_instance = instance
                instance
            }

        }

    }
}



class MyApp: Application() {

    private lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
    }

    fun getAppComponent(): AppComponent {
        return appComponent
    }
}


@Module
class AppModule(private val application: Application) {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getUserRepo(appDB: AppDB): IUserRepository {
        return appDB.userRepository()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getRoomDBInstance(context: Context): AppDB {
        return AppDB.getAppDBInstance(context)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppContext(): Context {
        return application.applicationContext
    }

}

And in my Manifest, I added this:
android:name=".configurations.MyApp"

I have normal transaction when the phone is disconnected from the debugger. and also I can see the databases and data when Im debugging. but my problem is when I hit debug again, all the data are gone and I have to repopulate all the test data again.
is there something wrong with my configurations?
by the way this is how I inject my repositories:
open class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    @Inject lateinit var userRepository: IUserRepository

    init {
        (application as MyApp).getAppComponent().inject(this)
        sharedUserId = sharedPrefs.getInt("userId",0)
        sharedCompanyId = sharedPrefs.getInt("companyId",0)
        sharedRoleId = sharedPrefs.getInt("roleId",0)
        sharedFullName = sharedPrefs.getString("fullName","")
        sharedApiToken = sharedPrefs.getString("apiToken","")
    }

}

Thanks in advance.

To clarify, you use Dagger directly, not Hilt (which is built ontop of Dagger, omptimized for Android)?

Unrelated to your issue, but your singleton getter function has a flaw in it (the same flaw that is in Google’s Room With a View CodeLab). Inside the synchronized block, you need to do a second check for whether the backing property is still null and return it if it isn’t before you start creating the instance.

How are you establishing that the data is gone?

@IvanWooll, every time I inspect the database right after the app is launch. all data is gone.

@Leviathan, I use Dagger, not Dagger-Hilt.

@Tenfour04, would you direct me to the correct way sir?

@jreloz There's nothing standing out in the samples you have provided in your question. Here's a guide to setting up Hilt in a project: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android
Once you understand how to use hilt to provide dependencies I recommend you take a look at the following: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room
Good luck

First line inside the synchronized block should be db_instance?.let { return it } Otherwise, any thread that calls this function after the first caller but having to wait on the synchronization block will create a duplicate instance that replaces a previous instance.

Okay, so this is a rookie mistake.
I have 'Clear app storage before deployment' option ticked. It needs to be unticked to prevent android studio from clearing apps storage.

